# Chat mentions from similar named user notifies all named users

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, notifications

I woke up this morning and had two notifications from stackoverflow js chat that another individual named Derek partook in:

[image]

Also,  is meta the best place to put this? I don't think this is a feature -  more like a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will only happen for 48 hours after inactivity in a room, and then it will stop.

Unless you are a room owner or moderator, in which case you always get them.

The subname pinging system has been in place for a long time and isn't changing. This is just its design.

Comment: It couldn't be changed to notify the user associated with the post from which the original comment came from?

Comment: There is no "post" referenced in those chat lines. If you literally type "@Derek", chat has no idea if which of the Dereks you intend to ping, so it just notifies both.